# OOM Killer is triggered despite free memory

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am having a problem where the OOM killer is being triggered some times. I have   researched in the internet and have found many related threads. But a few things   still puzzle me. I hope some one could help me.

Environment: iMX6 (32bit). 
User/Kernelspace split: 2G-2G
TotalRAm - 4GB

Some important logs:

**top invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0**
I see that it is trying to allocate 1 page of (contagious) memory (order=0) in the HIGHMEM zone (from gfp_mask). Please correct me if i am wrong.

**DMA free:1322780kB min:4492kB low:5612kB high:6736kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:84kB

DMA: 941*4kB (UEMC) 1211*8kB (UEMC) 1185*16kB (UEMC) 836*32kB (UEMC) 554*64kB

(UEMC) 295*128kB (UEMC) 106*256kB

HighMem free:480kB min:512kB low:2384kB high:4256kB active_anon:2021148kB inactive_anon:70364kB active_file:0kB

HighMem: 0*4kB 1*8kB (R) 0*16kB 7*32kB (R) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB 0*8192kB**

I believe the OOM-killer is triggered as the free Highmem (480KB) is below the min (512KB). Again please correct me if i am wrong.

My questions:
1. I thought the DMA_ZONE is only about 16MB, NORMAL_ZONE is upwards from 16MB 
   to about 896MB and the rest is HIGHMEM_ZONE. But the log shows more than 1GB 
   free pages (1322780kB) exist in the DMA_ZONE.
2. Why does not the kernel utilize this Zone for further allocation?

Morelogs: (taken out from the complete log):
**DMA per-cpu:

 CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0

 CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0

 CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0

 CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0

HighMem per-cpu:

 CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  51

 CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  20

 CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   4

 CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  14

active_anon:505287 inactive_anon:17591 isolated_anon:0

active_file:21 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:0

unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0

free:330815 slab_reclaimable:1134 slab_unreclaimable:3487

mapped:15956 shmem:25014 pagetables:1982 bounce:0

25046 total pagecache pages

983039 pages of RAM

331349 free pages

9947 reserved pages

2772 slab pages

543663 pages shared

0 pages swap cached**

cat /proc/pagetypeinfo
Page block order: 13
Pages per block:  8192

Free pages count per migrate type at order       0      1      2      3      4        5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13
Node    0, zone      DMA, type    Unmovable      1      0      9      8      3        1      0      1      1      1      1      0      1      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type  Reclaimable      4      5      5      1      2       0      1      1      1      0      1      0      1      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Movable      1      6      4      0      0        0      1      1      2      4      3      3      4     28
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Reserve      0      0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
Node    0, zone      DMA, type          CMA      1      1      2      0      0        0      0      0      1      1      0      0      1      3
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type    Unmovable     11      7      2      2      9        6      5      3      3      1      0      1      1      0
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type      Movable     23    201   4771   4084   1803      403    105     69     57     38     23     21      8     23
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type      Reserve      0      0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type          CMA      0      0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

Number of blocks type     Unmovable  Reclaimable      Movable      Reserve            CMA      Isolate
Node 0, zone      DMA            5            1           33            1             16            0
Node 0, zone  HighMem            2            0           62            1              0            0

I would be glad to post further logs if necessary.

Thankyou,
Srik

Comment: had some code put in comment by mistake not sure if a good answer but put it in answer below

Comment: any other suggstions?

Answer (score 0):

probably long shot but have you tried adding

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 80
```

to

/etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: that should stop applications from being able to request more memory than available but I could be WAY off base dont usually have to much in kernel for years....

Comment: thanks for your response. The current overcommit_memory is the default 0. I am not sure it this would help. Even if it helps, the application would not get the memory it desires. My question is the DMA_ZONE seems to be having about 1.3GB of memory free, why does not kernel use this memory for the allocation to a user space?

Comment: Not a Linux kernel expert... but it might not allow applications to access larger amounts of memory if even only some of the memory is protected. It could be possible that a high priority kernel level call needs the same memory that a user level application is trying to use and the user level would get denied the memory. Have you seen any logs where any smaller user level applications used the DMA_ZONE?

Answer (score 0):

The changes are high that you did run out of *virtual memory* because 32 bit kernel can only directly access 4 GB of virtual memory and there're heavy limitations on the usable address space for hardware access. For example, network adapter hardware acceleration could require memory in some specific address range and if you run out of RAM in that specific range, the system either has to run OOM Killer or kill your network adapter. And that's true even if your system has free available in some unrelated zone.

For details, try reviewing these links:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/564068/linux-oom-situation-32-bit-kernel
- https://serverfault.com/questions/548736/how-to-read-oom-killer-syslog-messages

and maybe this, too:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373312/oom-killer-doesnt-work-properly-leads-to-a-frozen-os

**TL;DR:** if you need more than 2 GB of RAM, install a 64 bit OS.